# Passing product id to content_ids for Facebook Pixel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to use **Facebook Pixel** to track **ViewContent** event on products. Facebook says that it's required to pass **content_ids** or contents and **content_type**.

I guess content_type should always be 'product' and I can write that manually but how can I pass product id dynamically to 'content_ids' on each product page?

```
fbq('trackSingle', 'myfacebookpixelid', 'ViewContent', {
    content_ids: ''
    content_type: 'product'
  })
```

I have a product.js page that is used as the product page and I have the product id as this.state.product._id

**How should I initialize FB Pixel on this page and how can I pass the product ID into content_ids?**

Any guidance is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself. I just had to pass the product id to the Facebook Pixel component on the Product page. Then I passed it to the ViewContent event in the content_ids.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).